# RSS feed created with PHP only shows the title in the feed reader

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am using the following PHP code to generate the XML for an RSS feed, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.  No short description is displayed in the feed reader, all I see is the title of the article.  Also, all of the articles say they were published at the same time.  This is the first time I have tried to setup an RSS feed, so I'm sure I've made several stupid mistakes.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");

$date = date(DATE_RFC822);

header('Content-type: text/xml');

echo ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n");
echo ("<rss version=\"2.0\">\n");
echo ("<channel>\n");
echo ("<lastBuildDate>$date</lastBuildDate>\n");
echo ("<pubDate>$date</pubDate>\n");
echo ("<title>my website name</title>\n");
echo ("<description><![CDATA[the description]]></description>\n");
echo ("<link>http://my-domain.com</link>\n");
echo ("<language>en</language>\n");

$ch=100;
while ($a = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $headline = htmlentities(stripslashes($a['subject']));
    $posturl = $a[perm_link];
    $content = $a['post'];
    $date = date(DATE_RFC822, $a['posted']);

    echo ("<item>\n");
    echo ("<title>$headline</title>\n");
    echo ("<link>$posturl</link>\n");
    echo ("<description><![CDATA[$content]]></description>\n");
    echo ("<guid isPermaLink=\"true\">$posturl</guid>\n");
    echo ("<pubDate>$date2</pubDate>\n");
    echo ("</item>\n");
}

echo ("</channel>\n");
echo ("</rss>\n");
```

Comment: please use a proper xml parser for this ...like [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Are you sure that $a['post'] contains the post?
2. Missing quotes for array index in $a[perm_link];
3. The variable you store the date in is called $date, while in the feed you're putting $date2;
4. (does not compromise the functionalities but) why did you declare that $ch var just before the loop?

Comment: 1. Yes, 100% sure.  I can see it in the XML file.

3. Thanks, not sure how I missed that one.  That fixes the date issue, and the other issue seems to be fixed now as well.